# How to secure a cutting disc on a smooth electric motor arbor..unthreaded

Tags: tools

How can I secure a cutting disc on a unthreaded motor arbor? I tied collars but the disc still wouldn't stay secure. Motor is a 3/4 hp, 1735 rpm, 5/8" smooth arbor. It has a slot or notch for a locking "key" but the cutting disc isn't notched for locking. Cutting disc is 6 1/2" x 1/8" x 5/8" hole
Thanks!

Comment: A little more info would be helpful what kind of grinder or saw. The make and model of the tool you are trying to use also. For example with a small grinder and a razor disk the lock nut needs to be put on backwards from the way a thick disk. Saws may be a diferent solution all together.

Comment: The motor is an old Emierson 3/4 hp, 1725 rpm, 5/8'' smooth arbor..no threads. It originally had a pulley for belts that locked on with an arbor "key".The cutting disc is 6 1/2" x 1/8'' x 5/8".  . The disc doesn't have a slot or notch I for the key. I tried using two Allen bolt collars but they didn't hold the disk tight enough.  Any solution for this will be appreciated!

Comment: I added more details but got no response. Can anyone answer?
Dick

Comment: Oh this is a standard motor shaft with a key way. Cutting disks usually need a flange that can apply pressure on both sides. I am not aware of a diy way to do this unless you have a lathe available.

Answer (score 1):

File an appropriately sized notch in the cutting disc and use a key. Obviously this depends on the disc material and will not work for all discs.

Comment: Good suggestion! I'll try making a notch in the disc. Thanks Aaron!

Comment: Whoops! Cutting a notch in the disc should allow me to use the key and make the disc turn......but the 1/8'' disc would still not be solid. The collars don't have a key notch and can''t  be up solid to the disc with the key in. ?????

Comment: oh i think i understand. In that case, you can take the key out, cut it to size, and then hold everything in place with the collars. you're pushing it though, in terms of safety. Sometimes it's just the wrong tool!

Comment: Aaron...thanks again. How would you cut the key? Grind it down?

Comment: i was thinking a file, but it depends on the cutting disc material. If it's a solid piece of bound abrasive, the only way might be to grind it, which is... tough to say the least.